# XPath in XML, how to get an access

Tags: html, xml, xpath, nodes

I would like to ask one question about XPath expression. How can I get access to specific node, if there are two elements with the same name? Here is short example of XML file for creating that XPath expression. I need an access into third row´s node with name CITY (how to get value of that). How to do that? Thx

```
<tournament name="WCH">
  <properties>
    <property object="tournament_stage" name="City"/>
    <property object="tournament_stage" name="Date"/>
    <property object="tournament_stage" name="Time"/>
  </properties>
  <properties>
    <property object="event" name="Live"/>
    <property object="event" name="Winner"/>
    <property object="event" name="Game Ended"/>
</tournament>
```

Comment: Show what have you tried so far. Also clarify what exactly you want to get. `name` attribute from 3rd `property` element or `property` element with `name` attribute that equal to "City" or what?

Comment: I need the value of attribute that equal to "City"

Comment: This what I publsihed is extract from some XML file. So probably won´t understand, if I would send you that Xpath. But if it would be better, i will send you that full XML file :)